# jboss ldap baseFilter

Tags: jboss, active-directory, ldap, jboss7.x

I found following option in standalone.xml of our jboss 7 installation:

```
<module-option name="baseFilter" value="(&amp;(objectClass=User)(sAMAccountName={0}))"/>
```

The &amp; instead & looks odd to me, but the login process of our service seems to work so far. Do you use & or &amp; in your configurations? Is it a general "masking" that is necessary for special characters that could be shell expanded or so?

Thanks for any thoughts on this.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

It's standard character escaping in XML. The ampersand character in XML files is used as prefix for **[XML character entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)**.

If you use **JBoss CLI** then use the ampersands without escaping.

```
/subsystem=security/security-domain=testLdapExample3/authentication=classic/login-module=LdapExtended:add( \
  code=LdapExtended, \
  flag=required, \
  module-options=[ \
    ("java.naming.factory.initial"=>"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"), \
    ("java.naming.provider.url"=>"ldap://ldaphost.jboss.org"), \
    ("java.naming.security.authentication"=>"simple"), \
    ("bindDN"=>"cn=Root,dc=jboss,dc=org"), \
    ("bindCredential"=>"secret1"), \
    ("baseCtxDN"=>"ou=People,o=example3,dc=jboss,dc=org"), \
    ("baseFilter"=>"(&(objectClass=User)(sAMAccountName={0}))"), \
    ("rolesCtxDN"=>"ou=Roles,o=example3,dc=jboss,dc=org"), \
    ("roleFilter"=>"(member={1})"), \
    ("roleAttributeID"=>"cn") \
  ])
```